# Making a dice game

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn C# on my own. I wanted to make a dice game that lets the user enter any number of dice that he or she wants. So if the user enters 10 dice, 10 list of the dice roll would appear next to each other. Here is where I can't figure it out. How can I let the user input any number of dice he or she wants? It would be impractical to use an array or list because I have to give each section of the 10 times or more. It would be nice to give a simple example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random numbergen = new Random();
        int dice1=0;
        int dice2=1;
        for (int counter = 0; counter <= 1; counter++)
        {
            while (dice1 != dice2)
            {
                dice1 = numbergen.Next(1, 7);
                dice2 = numbergen.Next(1, 7);
                if (dice1 == dice2)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine(dice1 + "\t" + dice2);
                    counter++;
                    dice1 = 0;
                    dice2 = 1;


                }
                else if (dice1 != dice2)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.WriteLine(dice1 + "\t" + dice2);
                }
                if (counter ==1 )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: It would be nice i you gave a simple example of the code you've written so far...

Comment: heres the code i have so far, but is there make any number of dice without making int dice 0 all the way to 100? @ David Arno

Comment: As this question has now been closed, I'd suggest you ask the question again, but include the code from the start this time. Good luck.

Comment: So what problem are you having with that code?  In what way is it not doing what you want?

Comment: Dice 1 and dice 2 represent the 2 dices that are being rolled. This program keeps rolling until until there is a pair between the two. I want to go one step farther then this, how would you enter any number number of dice without having to keep writing int. When i use arrays and loop, I keep having to refer back to a specific section of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you want a [List<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), something like this:

```
int size = 10; // Or user input
List<int> dice = new List<int>(size);
```

The form of the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an `Int32` argument pre-allocates that many items in the list.

Then, rather than `dice1 = numbergen.Next(1, 7);`, you have `dice[0] = ...`.

You'll obviously need a loop to generate the values and decide how you want to interpret your condition of two of them being equal (which will probably *also* require a loop of some sort), but if I'm understanding the question correctly, this should get you going.

(You can do something similar with an array, but lists are handy in other ways, as you can see from the first link.)

Alternatively, instead of pre-allocating and filling them in separately, you can allocate an empty list and then fill your items in with something more like:

```
int size = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    dice.Add(numbergen.Next(1, 7));
}
```

That's probably preferred by most people, but the difference should be pretty much negligible for this sort of work.

(And while you're at it, change your `for` loop to a `while` and change `counter` to a `bool` with a more useful name...)